# Increase the width of div ignoring the width of container-parent (and use x scrollbar)

Tags: css, html, sass, haml

Let me explain with madskillz.

1. The current status
   [image: wrong]

I'm doing a gallery which is formed by array of urls.
Haml code:

```
%section#content
  %form
    %fieldset
      #gallery
        %i.gallery_title Все категории
        .cat-item
          - @all.zip(@all_thumbs).each do |full, thumb|
            .cat-pic
              %a{href:"#{full}", rel:'lightbox[roadtrip]'}
                %img{src:"#{thumb}", alt:"Панно \"#{full}\""}
              %br
              %input{type:'radio', name:'picture', value:"#{full}"}
```

Css (sass)

```
#content
  margin: auto
  margin-top: 25px
  padding-bottom: 100px
  width: 950px
  align: center
form
  display: inline-block
fieldset
  background-color: darken($bg, 10%)
  border-radius: 10px /* wtf firefox */
  @include round(10px)
.cat-item
  height: 150px
  overflow-x: scroll
  overflow-y: hidden
  background: $bg
  @include round(10px)
  min-width: auto !important
.cat-pic
  margin-left: 5px
  margin-top: 5px
  height: 120px
  float: left
  input
    width: 100px
```

I want to put all pictures in one row in one line and add a x-axis scrollbar.
I'm very tired of css. Hope you can help.
[image: i_want]

Comment: Please give an example or a fiddle (jsfiddle.net).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working sample of HTML w/ CSS to achieve a result much like you are looking for:
http://jsfiddle.net/rey6G/

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    #Outer {
      border: #000000 1px solid;
      background-color: #FFFFFF;
      width: 500px;
      overflow-x: scroll;
      overflow-y: hidden;
    }
    #Inner {
      list-style: none;
      white-space: nowrap;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    #Inner > li {
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: top;
      margin-left: 5px;
      border: #CCCCCC 1px solid;
      padding: 10px;
      width: 80px;
      height: 80px;
      white-space: normal;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="Outer">
    <ul id="Inner">
      <li>Something</li>
      <li>Something Else</li>
      <li>Another thing</li>
      <li>Thing 4</li>
      <li>Badda thing</li>
      <li>Wee Thing</li>
      <li>This thing</li>
      <li>That thing</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**NOTE** This uses `display: inline-block` which does not work in very old versions of IE (IE7 and below I believe). I doubt this is a concern, but felt I should bring it up!